# Call function passing array's

Tags: c++, c, arrays, function

I want to enter the text and specific character. 
After that i want to count how many those characters contain in the text.

**My code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int counting(char text[], char character);
int main()
{
    char text[20];
    char character;
    int a;
    printf("Enter text!\n");
    scanf("%s", text);
    printf("Enter character!\n");
    scanf("%s", character);
    a= counting(text, character);
    printf("Text contain %d character!\n", a);

}
```

**And the counting function**

```
int counting(char text[], char character)
{
int i=0;
int counter=0;
while(text[i] != '\0')
    {
        if  (text[i]==character)
            {
                counter++;
            }           
    }
i++;
return counter;
}
```

**Error:** 
[image]

Comment: @Jayesh it doesn't work it show's me and error pic: http://pokit.org/get/?c98220d3df65ee348290be9f7bbaf255.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line for reading the character needs to be:

```
scanf(" %c", &character);
```

Also,

```
scanf("%s", text);
```

is not safe. If the user enter a string that is longer than 19 characters, you will be writing over unauthorized memory, which will lead to undefined behavior.

Use

```
scanf("%19s", text);
```

Comment: @R Sahu entire code looks like this now but still doesn't work 
http://pastebin.com/8gyLVDYQ  It shows me like this http://pokit.org/get/?84ce24d4a7733a73b64b54ba018ebe8b.jpg I can't even enter the character

Comment: @t3cho It correctly executed. what is your input for character? In screen shot i see you have not input any character.

Comment: @t3cho, You are using `"%c"` instead of `" %c"`. The extra space is necessary to you don't end up reading the `'\n'` from the previous line.

Answer (score 2):

In function `int counting(...)`

```
while(text[i] != '\0')
    {
        if  (text[i]==character)
            {
                counter++;
            }           
    }
i++;
```

Need `i++` inside your `while..loop`.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.

1)You are reading the specific character as a string so you have to change `scanf("%s", character);` to `scanf(" %c", character);`

2)In function `counting()` `i++` needs to be in while loop so you don't enter an infinite loop.